# Is there a word for Chinese songs that rhyme like Jay Chou's 迷迭香 and JJ Lin's 伟大的渺小?

Tags: word, word-requests, poetry, lyrics, songs

Every single line in Jay Chou's song "Rosemary" ends with the "ao" sound:

```
ni de zui jiao 
wei wei shang qiao 
xing gan de wu ke jiu yao 
xiang xiang bu dao 
ru ci xin tiao 
ni de yi qie dou xiang yao 
ruan xing de yin liao 
shang sheng de qi pao 
wo jiang dui ni de xi hao 
yi ping zhuang quan he diao 
zhe li zui bu que jiu shi re nao 
ni shan qing 
gei yong bao 
zhu huo zai ran shao 
you mou zhong qing diao 
yan shen shi jiao le ji miao 
guan yu ni de wu dao 
ni yong lan de niu dong zhe yao 
shou bu liao 
ni sui feng piao yang de xiao 
you mi die xiang de wei dao 
yu dai bo he wei de sa jiao 
dui wo fa chu lian ai de xun hao 
ni you ya de xiang yi zhi mao 
dong zuo qing ying de wei rao 
ai de tian wei man yan fa xiao 
ai mei lai de gang hao 

ruan xing de yin liao 
shang sheng de qi pao 
wo jiang dui ni de xi hao 
yi ping zhuang quan he diao 
zhe li zui bu que jiu shi re nao 
ni shan qing gei yong bao 
zhu huo zai ran shao 
you mou zhong qing diao 
yan shen shi jiao le ji miao 
guan yu ni de wu dao 
ni yong lan de niu dong zhe yao 
shou bu liao 
ni sui feng piao yang de xiao 
you mi die xiang de wei dao 
yu dai bo he wei de sa jiao 
dui wo fa chu lian ai de xun hao 
ni you ya de xiang yi zhi mao 
dong zuo qing ying de wei rao 
ai de tian wei man yan fa xiao 
ai mei lai de gang hao
```

Same with JJ Lin's "Little Big Us":

```
Yi duo mei gui bei ci wei rao 
ye xu ta ye ke wang yong bao
Hai tun lian shang zong you wei xiao 
ye xu lei bei da hai xi diao 
shi bu rang ren zhi dao
Ni wo xing fu huo nan ao
Hao huo zao cang jin wai biao de gu ao
Qi shi wo xiang yao 
yi zhong mei meng shui bu zhao
Yi zhong xin zang de kuang tiao
Wa jie jie xian bu bei liao dao 
ben pao yi kao
Wo xin zhong zui xiang yao kan ni kan guo de lang chao
Pei ni fang si de nian shao
Cong ni yan shen neng zhao dao jie yao
Yu zhou yi si yi hao
Wei da bing fei cou qiao
Wo wo de shou wo hao
Wo huo xu hen miao xiao
Ye jue bu tao
Ye wan xing chen gao diao shan yao 
ye xu shi zui hou de wan shao
Hou niao neng zi you fei de gao
ye xu shi liu lang de fu hao
ke shi shui you zhi dao
Ni wo ceng you guo jian ao
Ba ke tao han wei jin you de jiao ao
Qi shi wo xiang yao 
yi zhong mei meng shui bu zhao
Yi zhong xin zang de kuang tiao
Wa jie jie xian bu bei liao dao
ben pao yi kao
Wo xin zhong zui xiang yao 
kan ni kan guo de lang chao
Pei ni fang si de nian shao
Cong ni yan shen neng zhao dao jie yao
Yu zhou yi si yi hao
Wei da bing fei cou qiao
Wo wo de shou wo hao
Wo huo xu hen miao xiao
Na zhi qian wo yao bao 
ni zai ni liu ren chao
Dong ni mei ge lei he xiao
Cong ni gu shi zhong zhao dao mei miao
Nu li bu hui tu lao
Ai bing fei cou qiao
Wo men wo de shou wo hao
Wo men jiu suan hen miao xiao
Ye jue bu tao
Wo de shou wo hao
Wo you duo miao xiao
Ye zuo de dao
```

Out of all the different types of [rhyme schemes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhyme_scheme#Notation_and_examples), this one in English would be called a "[monorhyme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monorhyme)", but I wonder if there's a Chinese word for it because the above examples are not only monorhymes but all end in the sound spelled "ao", which is not the case for English monorhymes, such as the example given on the Wikipedia page for monorhymes:

```
Is like a spell to make me swear
Of my quick, surreptitious stare
She wrings the water from her hair
And turning smiles to see me there
```

The type of rhyme I'm looking for, does not need to end always in "ao", it could also end always in "shi" or something else. I just want to know if there's a Chinese word for the type of poem/song given.

[Google Translate does give a translate for monorhyme](https://www.google.com/search?q=translate&oq=translate&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.1107j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8): 一韵 which just means "one rhyme", and could easily just be Google's educated guess, knowing that "mono" means "one".

Comment: Monorhyme sounds powerful and naturally attracting, similar to the core recursive reasoning/algo in science from which transcendence becomes possible...

Answer (score 3):

We call it 单押 in Chinese，which means that sentences have the same or similar vowels between sentences. The end of each sentence has the same vowel. It's a type of rhyme scheme，not a type of music though. You can find it in many types of music.

Here's some other examples:

- 东风破 (by Jay Chou),
- 一路向北 (by Jay Chou),
- 禅舞不二 (by Wilber Pan).

Comment: I got rid of this post's "Community Wiki" status which isn't really appropriate here (it's mostly for facilitating community editing).  [Please let me know if I'm missing something.]

Answer (score 2):

> the above examples are not only monorhymes but all end in the sound spelled "ao", which is not the case for English monorhymes

No. There is no such thing as "spelling" in Chinese. The examples you gave are in pinyin, a phonetic transliteration system, which means the same sound is always transcribed the same. If you put them into proper Chinese, the first few lines of 迷迭香 will be like this:

```
你的嘴角
微微上翹 
性感的無可救藥
```

As you can see, the written forms of the last character of each line (the rhyming part) have nothing in common. They just have the same ending sound. This is the same with your English example (words have different spellings but all end with the 'air' sound). So the distinction you were trying to make does not exist. It is just monorhyme in English.

As for the Chinese name, I assume what you mean is a rhyme scheme where the whole song/poem uses only one rhyme, without changing rhyme. If so, that's called 一韵到底. If you change rhyme in the middle of the song/poem, it (the action of changing rhyme) is called 换韵.

The term that the previous answer gives, 单押, is not exact. The examples you gave happen to be both 一韵到底 and 单押, but the terms themselves mean two different things. 单押 means only the last character of each line is in rhyme, in contrary to 双押, where the last two characters in each line rhyme respectively. For example, in "你的嘴角 微微上翹", only 角 and 翘 rhyme. In "你的嘴角 每分每秒",  嘴 rhymes with 每 and 角 rhymes with 秒. There is even 三押, which is even more challenging.

Obviously, a song/poem can be 单押 and 换韵, or 一韵到底 and 双押. The two set of terms are orthogonal.